# Import Mutliple Csv File as Data Frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, csv

I want to import multiple csv file as data frame. I try the code below, but the elements of my list are still character. Thanks for your help!

```
new_seg <-(list.files (path=csv, pattern="^new.*?\\.csv",recursive = T)) 

for (i in 1:length(new_seg))
assign(new_seg[i], data.frame(read.csv(new_seg[i])))

new_seg
[1] "new_ Seg_grow_1mm.csv" "new_ Seg_grow_3mm.csv" "new_ Seg_resample.csv"

class('new_ Seg_grow_1mm.csv')
[1] "character"
```

Comment: Have a look at using `map_df()`, such as here https://dominicroye.github.io/en/2019/import-excel-sheets-with-r/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `full.names = T` in the `list.files` function. Then I typically use `lapply` to load the files in. Also, in my code below I use `pattern = "\\.csv"` because that's what I needed for this to work with my files.

```
csv <- getwd()
new_seg <- (list.files(path=csv, pattern="\\.csv", recursive = T, full.names = T))

new_seg_dfs <- lapply(new_seg, read.csv)
```

Now, `new_seg_dfs` is a list of data frames.

P.S. seems that you maybe set your working directory beforehand since your files are showing up, but it's always good practice to show the every step you took in these examples.